# Получение текста, который не под каким тегом

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть такой html код:

```html
<div class='main'>
  <strong> текст1 </strong>
    текст2
  <strong> текст3 </strong>
    текст4
</div>
```

Таких текстов может быть много, мне нужно получить именно текст2 и текст4, которые не в strong при помощи python3  и selenium

Comment: xpath `//div[@class='main']/text()` должен дать то, что вы хотите. Только пустые строки убрать надо будетэ

Comment: вот такую ошибку выдает  
The result of the xpath expression "//div[@class='reconciledDetailsAttributes']/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
и еще нужно допустим получить только текст4, как это сделать?

Comment: Я про вашу реализацию xpath не знаю ( а так, чтоб взять только его в конце [3]

Comment: А у него нету как в php, execute чтоб коллекцию получить и evaluate, которому все равно, что возвращается ?

Comment: можно по-подробнее?)

Comment: про три или про evaluate?

Comment: про evaluate и этот способ

Comment: счет в xpath  идет с 1 - между div первым strong text()[1], между strongs -[2], последний [3]

Comment: если убрать text() вернется  элемент, а с текстом, как вы видите Text, что с ним делать в selenium я не знаю